# like box stream does not show stories

Tags: stream, facebook-likebox

Since I changed my fan page to the timeline, all of my posts (now called stories?) are no longer showing in the like box.  Has the code changed to include timeline stories?

Comment: can view at www.novamidwife.org

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because FB now hides activity that's older than 30 days in the LIke Box stream feed.  I had a similar problem and, once I put up a new post on the FB page I manage, the stream showed up again.  The stream only showed that new post that I just put up, but included a link to 'Show More' below.

So if you have no activity in the last 30 days, your Like Box plugin on your website will be empty as far as showing you stream.  If you have 1 post/activity in the last 30 days, only that 1 post will show, but there will be a link below to "Show More," which will reveal all activity older than 30 days.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The box works (shows posts) in IE I just looked and didn't have to change compatibility view) but not Google Chrome since I switched to timeline.

Website is www.novamidwife.org

Answer (score 0):

go to your website page, turn off compatibility view and it should work. worked for me anyway

Comment: its in the tools menu on explorer

Comment: There are posts made on the page almost daily:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Northern-Virginia-Midwifery/115869881626

Can one turn off compatibility view in Chrome?  Thanks so much for your responses.

Comment: The box works (shows posts) in IE I just looked and didn't have to change compatibility view) but not Google Chrome since I switched to timeline.